# How can I use one method with several Propel models in Symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I have a method for getting all the rows from a table in the database with the order specified in the arguments:

```
public static function getAllOrderedBy($orders = null)
    {
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        if(is_array($orders))
        {
            foreach($orders as $column => $order)
            {
                if($order == 'asc')
                {
                    $criteria->addAscendingOrderByColumn($column);
                }
                else if($order == 'desc')
                {
                    $criteria->addDescendingOrderByColumn($column);
                }
            }
        }
        else if($orders != null)
        {
            $criteria->addAscendingOrderByColumn($orders);
        }
        return self::doSelect($criteria);
    }
```

This method takes place in the `PagePeer` class, but I want to use it with several models, like `LinkPeer` or `SubjectPeer`.
I could copy and paste this code from one model to another, but I want to ask if is there a better way to have this method available for all of these classes?

It's not a problem if the usage will change, so I'll not call `PagePeer:getAllByOrder(PagePeer::TITLE)` but something else, I just dont want to copy this code to every model it is used in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can accomplish that.

- Propel behviors. Documentation [states](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.4/Behaviors) that you can add static method to your peer classes via `staticMethods()`
- Symfony Mixins. They were documented in `The Definitive Guide to symfony 1.0`. See [Chapter 17 - Extending Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/17-Extending-Symfony#chapter_17_mixins). In newer verions of this guide information about mixins was removed, but it seems that code of sfMixer class hasn't been changed ([sfMixer in sf1.0](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.0/lib/util/sfMixer.class.php) and [sfMixer in sf1.4](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/addon/sfMixer.class.php))

Comment: I tried making a behavior class as you suggested, but I can't make it work. Every time I want to rebuild my model I get the following message: `Propel behavior "peerplus" is not registered`. I put this new class in the project folders lib/behavior/PeerPlusBehavior.php file, and added the next line at the end of propel.ini: `propel.behavior.peerplus.class = lib.behavior.PeerPlusBehavior`.  And of course added the behavior to the schema.yml too where needed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OK, found what was wrong. In the schema.yml you have to use `_propel_behaviors` not just `_behaviors`, and list the behavior under that.
In addition you have to extend the `SfPropelBehaviorBase` in your Behavior class (not the simple `Behavior`), and everything just works fine after that. Thanks for your help!